# Fastest way to repeat a vector in Eigen c++

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

I have two vectors:

```
Eigen::Array2d A;
Eigen::Array4d B;
```

Basically, the vector A contains some value like

```
0.3
0.7
```

The idea is that I would like to get the vector B as follows

```
0.3
0.3
0.7
0.7
```

What is the fastest way to do that? I want the "fastest" way because I have to do this manipulation a lot of times. I know that I could use a mixture of `replicate`, `transpose()`, and `Map` functions to do it but it won't be so fast.

Should I use pointers, instead? Let's say the first two rows of B would point to the first row of A, and the two last rows of B would point to the last row of A? Does it make sense?

Comment: What about a simple `for` loop that puts the elements in the right positions, possibly parallelized? The memory access pattern is probably the most crucial part here.

Comment: Have you measured that "it won't be so fast" or are you just assuming wildly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eigen: replicate items along one dimension without useless allocations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110917/eigen-replicate-items-along-one-dimension-without-useless-allocations)

Answer (score 0):

**Perhaps a simple "for" loop?**

Assuming your vectors contain doubles:

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.rows(); i++){
    double cur = A(i);
    B(2*i)     = cur;
    B(2*i + 1) = cur;
}
```

Eigen tends to optimize looping over vectors. The temporary is to avoid multiple access operations of A(i). You will also want to set row-major/column-major storage order correctly so memory access is as fast as possible.

I can't *guarantee* this is the fastest way, since I haven't benchmarked it, but my intuition tells me it would be faster than using several built-in Eigen functions together.