# Eigen3 Scale a Matrix

Tags: eigen3, image-scaling

The following opencv calls allows me to scale (up or down) an image based on a floating >>scale<< value and an existing cv::Mat image objetc:

```
cv::Mat resized(image.rows * scale, image.cols * scale, CV_8UC3);
cv::resize(image, resized, resized.size(), 0, 0);
```

Is there something similar to be able to perform such a transformation with matrices in Eigen3. I have been trying to read the Scaling documentation available but I am not able to make any sense of it and if it is actually meant for this.

How would you go from a 1000x1000 matrix to a 2000 x 2000 matrix ( interpolating the values)?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can use index a matrix by a `LinSpaced` expression, as demonstrated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46111789/, but that does not do any interpolation (and that is not really what Eigen matrices were designed to do). You can map between OpenCV and Eigen-types and use each others operations if you like.

Comment: In the end it is a matrix operation but maybe it is too specific for Eigen. I was thinking that maybe there exists a combination of operations that can do this. Having to go to OpenCV to do the sclaling and afterwards going back to Eigen seems a bit of an overkill.

Comment: Well, the linked answer does work with Eigen, but always takes the nearest neighbor instead of interpolating With some trickery you may be able to simulate linear interpolation with that (but unlikely as efficient as OpenCV). Eigen matrices mostly handle linear algebra ("matrix operation" is a very broad term ...)

Comment: As per the documentation "The method LinSpaced(size, low, high) is only available for vectors and one-dimensional arrays; it yields a vector of the specified size whose coefficients are equally spaced between low and high." Hence it seems I can't use it on a Matrix and it only generates values from low to high as per the size step specified ... pretty far away from interpolation but also quite difficult to use for a Matrix given some values specified in a smaller Matrix.

Comment: To scale a 1000x1000 matrix to 2000x2000, you can write: `mat(ArrayXi::LinSpaced(2000,0,1000-1),ArrayXi::LinSpaced(2000,0,1000-1))`